# create table inside the existing database. but user choose the database name using input variable

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, xampp

I'm trying to connect to a database and create a table based on the user's input, but I'm getting this error: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given`

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector

def add_tb():
    host='localhost'
    port='3306'
    user='root'
    password=''
    database =input('type the database name you want to add the table inside of it: ')
    
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host, port, user, password, database)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    tablename=input('what the name of table u want to create ?:')
    mycursor.execute(f'create table {tablename} (name varchar (200), kelas int (4))') 

add_tb()
```

But I'm gettting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\ALDOBOT\buattabel.py", line 18, in <module>
    add_tb()
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\ALDOBOT\buattabel.py", line 13, in add_tb
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host, port, user, password, database)
  File "C:\Users\NBUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 273, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
PS C:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton> & C:/Users/NBUSER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/NBUSER/Documents/ARTOFWAR/PITON/02-piton/ALDOBOT/buattabel.py
type database you wanttest123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\ALDOBOT\buattabel.py", line 18, in <module>
    add_tb()
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\ALDOBOT\buattabel.py", line 13, in add_tb
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host, port, user, password, database)
  File "C:\Users\NBUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 273, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NBUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 72, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
PS C:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton> & C:/Users/NBUSER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/NBUSER/Documents/ARTOFWAR/PITON/02-piton/ALDOBOT/buattabel.py
type the database name you want to add the table inside of it: test123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\ALDOBOT\buattabel.py", line 16, in <module>
    add_tb()
  File "c:\Users\NBUSER\Documents\ARTOFWAR\PITON\02-piton\ALDOBOT\buattabel.py", line 10, in add_tb
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host, port, user, password, database)
  File "C:\Users\NBUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 273, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NBUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 72, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: it is allowed basically but checlc the database name against the tablename

Comment: i already post the problem i facing in, 

actually what i want is :
when user try to create a table in a database, but before the user can do it. they have to type or mention the database base name. so that's why i try to make the database become a varibale input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you get is because `mysql.connector.connect()` uses `**kwargs` in order to be able to take an arbitrary number of keyword arguments ("kwargs" means "keyword arguments"), that's why it does not take arguments in a specific order.

It needs to be provided with `key=value` pair format.

This is how you need to use it:

```py
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, port=port, user=user, password=password, database=database)
```

[see more argument names here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)

Comment: well, that's work..!! thank you so much. i got what i want to achieve..  veryhelpfull..!!